# Why can't get font awesome 4.7 version icon by default?

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome, font-face

I can't get font awesome icons. So I inspect in the page and found

```
    .fa{
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    }
```

So I change value and give !important like

```
    .fa{
    font-family: "FontAwesome !important";
    font-weight: 400;
    }
```

It's working but, is it correct method? What should I do ?

screen shot of code highlight in red color -
[image]

Comment: Why are you changing the font css they are developed by the Fontawesome itself, you should avoid doing such things. I don't think its problem with CSS, if you post the code here we will able to understand whats the issue. Please include minimal reproducible code here

Comment: Sorry, to ask you but What is minimal reproducible code ?

Comment: It means to recreate a problem you are facing, here is the article which will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example